# ADF Interpretation

Tags: interpretation, lags, augmented-dickey-fuller

below is my ADF test for regression residuals. I use alpha=5%

My interpretation is : my residuals are non-stationary as my model does not take into account the 4 lags suggested by ADF. In other words, my residuals would be stationary only if i take in consideration the 4 lags in the model

Is this correct?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Such details can usually be found in the software documentation. You have not shown what software has produced the output, so we cannot be 100% sure. However, we can guess that the ADF test specification used 4 lags* and found a $p$-value of just under 0.05. Thus you can reject $H_0$ of presence of a unit root in favour of stationarity at a 5% significance level.

*The DF test does not include any lags, but the ADF does. *A* stands for *augmented*, and that means inclusion of some lags.

Comment: thanks for your response. I use Python and below is my code.  I am struggling to understand this. I have a regression model, let's say y = b0+b1x1+e which gives me some residuals. I test then the residuals with ADF. I found the residuals are stationary at 4 lags. If i had found  15 lags what would have been the difference? My understanding is 4 lags means i need to transform the model with for 4 lags in order to make it stationary and the conclusion is it is not.  I am not sure if i missed something here?

 result = adfuller(residuals, maxlag=lag)

Comment: @Ant, the `adfuller` function does not care where the first argument came from. It is only you who knows these are residuals from some model. For `adfuller`, this is just a time series. Lags in the ADF test are w.r.t. to first-differenced `residuals` (the first argument of the `adfuller` function) alone and not related to the original model that you are considering.

Comment: this is understood, thanks. However, when the test finds 4 lags stationarity implies residuals need to lag at 4 in order to be stationary (otherwise are non-stationary). If i don't make any change in residuals (in the model) how can i conclude they are stationary? If i conclude my residuals are stationary at 4 lags it does not mean is stationary at lag 0 which is the default residuals. Sorry if i don't make myself clear

Comment: @Ant, no *residuals need to lag at 4 in order to be stationary* is incorrect (and does not even make sense, technically speaking). The lags are used for specifying the test regression appropriately, but the conclusion of the ADF test applies to the original series.

Comment: It makes more sense. But i am not sure i can understand the purpose of lags. I mean if the ADF passes and this means the series is stationary, what does 4 lags mean ?

Comment: @Ant, it means that the *A* in ADF stands for four lags in the model that is used for carrying out the ADF test. Look for $\Delta y_{t-1},\dots,\Delta y_{t-p+1}$ in the model in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test)). (Or it could be 4-1=3, as Wikipedia uses lags between $t-1$ and $t-p+1$; you can dig into the help file for the `adfuller` function to find out exactly.)

Comment: thank you very much :)